Get Observable value even if never emit
I would like to have the value of an observable at given instant, even if this one didn't had any value, getting undefined/error is acceptable. But my code is currently waiting the observable to emit a value (logic !)
I have a service, and can't modify it :
   export class MyService {
     private readonly isEnable$ = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1)
        
     public init(isEnable: boolean) {
       this.isEnable$.next(isEnable);
     }
    
     public getFoo() {
       return this.isEnable$.pipe(
        map((isEnable: booelan) => isEnable ? foo : bar)
       )
     }
   }

In my code i'm using this service to retrieve informations. And I'm on a case where i can't initialise isEnable$.
So when I'm doing this, nothing happend, and this is normal.
this.myservice.getFoo().pipe(
  tap((value) => console.log(value))
).subscribe();

I would like to have and error or undefined, or empty string, without waiting isEnable$ to emit.
So my workarround is :
race(
  this.myservice.getFoo(),
  of('').pipe(delay(1)),
).pipe(
  tap((value) => console.log(value)) //got '' when not initialized, and got corrrect value when it is.
).subscribe()

First, can someone exaplain me why my first observable complete faster than 1ms ? It will always be true ?
Is there a better way to achieve this ?
Thanks !

How do you know it completed faster than 1ms? You don't have any complete handler there. Or you mean it emitted faster than 1ms?

race return the first complete observable right ? so if it return getFoo, that mean it faster than the delay(1) ?

race() will stay subscribed to the first Observable that emits and unsubscribes the others. This means that it doesn't react to complete notifications. With the race() Observable you want to find out if the this.myservice.getFoo() call emits a value immediately?

just use startWith

@martin yes i want to know if it emit value immediatly, if not, get undefined.

@maxime1992 in one case, it will emit undefined, in the other case it will emit twice. hmm not sure that's what i want

So you can either use distinctUntilChanged OR not send anything and if after some time you judge it's taking too long then use a timeout and catch + emit a default value

You have to use another stream that will emit immediately, and use RxJs combination operator. You can use concat (It will also preserve the order).
ngOnInit(): void {

    concat(
      of(null),
      this.myservice.getFoo().pipe(tap((value) => console.log(value)))
    ).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });


    setTimeout(() => {
      this.myservice.init(true);
    }, 3000);
  }

